# CNTK add a Bidirectional LSTM Layer

Tags: c#, cntk

From here: [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Hands-On-Labs-Language-Understanding#solution-3-bidirectional-recurrent-model)

I am asking how C# could implement such a function:

In Brainscript:

```
BiRecurrentLSTMLayer {outDim} = {
    F = RecurrentLSTMLayer {outDim, goBackwards=false}
    G = RecurrentLSTMLayer {outDim, goBackwards=true}
    apply (x) = Splice (F(x):G(x))
}.apply
```

The function is implemented in the Sequential:

```
hiddenDim = 150      ##### changed from 300 to 150

model = Sequential (
    EmbeddingLayer {embDim} :
    ###OneWordLookahead :                   ##### removed
    BatchNormalizationLayer {} :
    BiRecurrentLSTMLayer {hiddenDim} :
    BatchNormalizationLayer {} :
    DenseLayer {labelDim}
)
```

An LSTM is implemented here: [LSTMClassifier](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp/Common/LSTMSequenceClassifier.cs)

I have got this so far:

```
Function BiRecurrentLSTMLayer(Variable input, int outDim)
{

    Function F = Layers.LSTMLayer(input, outDim, 50, 35, 50, Device, "");
    Function G = Layers.LSTMLayer(input, outDim, 50, 35, 50, Device, "");

    return CNTK.CNTKLib.Splice(new VariableVector() { F, G }, null, "");
}
```

As you can see, there is no F of X'ing! Or go-Backwards...

To get the LSTM 'forward' and 'backward' setting, how to splice, and add as an array function?

EDIT:

I have dabbled with, and cant find a spot of documentation on: `CNTK.CNTKLib.ForwardBackward` see the code:

```
Function F = LSTMLayer(input, numOutput / 2, embedDim, hiddenDim / 2, cellDim, device, "");
Function G = LSTMLayer(input, (int)((numOutput / 2.0) + 0.5D), embedDim, hiddenDim / 2, cellDim, device, "");

return CNTK.CNTKLib.ForwardBackward(G, F, blankTokenId, delayConstraint, name);
```

but get the error:

> System.ApplicationException: 'Reduction operation ReduceElements: number (1) of reduction axes exceeds the rank (0) of the operand shape '[]'.

Comment: Well, it must be too hard? No answers or comments...